# delete lines with specific string in specific colomn bash

Tags: bash

testfile:

```
1|2|3|4|Test|6
1|2|3|4|Test|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|Test|6
1|Test|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|Test|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
```

The output should be after deletion :

```
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|Test|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Use awk

awk -F"|" '$5 != "Test" {print $0}' testfile

Comment: @steve-wright which command will be faster the one in answer or awk -F"|" '$5 != "Test" {print $0}' testfile

Comment: @Sourabh The one mentioned in @Aaron his comment. It avoids calling an extra binary `cat`

Comment: @Aaron you are correct. I didn't have access to a unix system when I wrote my answer. I couldn't remember where the filename went when it is passed as a parameter

Comment: I'm happy with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
awk -F"|" '$5 ~ /[[:digit:]]/' file.txt
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|Test|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
```

> Explanation -

- `F'|'`  : Set the "|" as Field Separator
- `$5 ~ /[[:digit:]]/` : Checking 5th column if it contain digit or not.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '/([^|]*\|){4}Test/d' testfile
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|Test|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
1|2|3|4|5|6
```

Comment: It would fail for `1|2|3|4|5|Test`, removing the line when it shouldn't ; You should anchor your regex by prefixing it with a `^`

Comment: Also you should match `|` after `Test` if you want to avoid removing `1|2|3|4|TestingSomethingElse|6`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It's good practice to include a little explanation with your answer/code.